# Why this simple polygon-to-star does not work in a particular document

Tags: mesh, scale

I am trying to repeat this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1RPYlTl_uI&t=45s

In a certain document, the "s for scale" does nothing in case of a polygon:

[image]

In case of a cylinder, it shortens the edges instead of moving them to the center. Can it be, there is some switch on in this document, which prevents the scaling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have the "individual origins" set as transform pivot point.
Change it to "median point"
[image]